# Concurrently npm with React Js

Tags: npm, concurrently

I have a project which is created using Node express and React Js. The server(Node) `package.json` as follows. It uses [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to start both server and client as once using `npm run dev`. The server uses port `5000` and the client uses port `3000` And the Folder structure as follows.

```
/
|
|-mysample
   |
   |-client
   |   |-.env
   |   |-package.json
   |   |-src
   |-server.js
   |-package.json
```

**package.json(mysample)**

```
{
  "name": "mysample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Sample",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.8",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
}
```

How can I use `concurrently` npm package to start two react js projects which uses port `3000` for admin and `8000` for client.

```
   /
    |-ebook_admin
       |
       |-client
       |   |-.env
       |   |-package.json
       |   |-src
       |   |-public
       |   |
       |-package.json
       |-src
       |-public
       |-.env
```

Comment: Did you see my answer (below)?

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correctly, you can take a look at one of my projects here https://github.com/chriskavanagh/mern-shopping-list/blob/master/package.json to see how as long as you've set up a proxy here https://github.com/chriskavanagh/mern-shopping-list/blob/master/client/package.json changing the port to 8000.

This is the backend package.json

`"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},`

and

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8000",` in your client package.json

Answer (score 0):

Solution is Here, first of all install concurrently(npm).

```
"scripts": {
"client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
"start": "nodemon server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"cd server && npm server"\ \"npm run client"\"
```

Than in your CLI: npm run dev
It's work! SkraJ5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have the same configurations. How can we use this to debug the front and backend concurrently? What would be the launch setting configuration to debug both together?